# Sharing my XCode projects without letting others see it's pseudo code

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, security

A client of mine would like to have a part of the functionality I wrote for a camera-application. However I don't want to let the client see any of the source code I made.

He mentioned a .dll file in windows which enables the application to be encrypted. Is there any support for Xcode for these kind of functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to create a Static Library, into which you can drop all the functionality that you want to provide to your client ... without revealing the actual code you did.

[Here's a tutorial you can refer to](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/).